# File is not creating in proper place In R script

Tags: r

I have a R script. In which I am storing a path in a variable and call it in program 
R script:-

```
args <- "/media/folder"
result <- paste0(args,"/folder_a/result")
df <- read.table("/home/media/abc.txt", header = F)
a0 <-  df[df$Copy_No=="cn=0",]
write.csv(a0,paste(result,"c0.csv",sep="/"))
```

It works when I use these in R terminal but when I am using these commands under R script the result is generating where the R script is present. Where I am wrong?

Comment: What is the returned path when you run getwd() in the terminal and in the R script?

Comment: @Jelle it returns the path where the script is present. script is present in script folder.    /media/folder/script

Comment: Are you using an external terminal or the terminal of R? I think changing your working directory using setwd() will fix it.

Comment: @Jelle I am using external terminal (/media/folder/script) to run R script then script is not generating file in proper place. but when I am using R terminal and commands on terminal  it is generating file in proper place.

Comment: Is there is an another way to write csv ?

Answer (score -2):

When your run an R script the working directory is that of the script by default.
Use the name of the entire path in your 'args'. e.g.,:

```
args <- "C:/media/folder"
```

Comment: `/media/folder` is the name of an entire path in Linux

Comment: Yes,     /media/folder     is the entire path